# Write a php code to be seo permalink url according to current htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Below is example a famous `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

What I know here, the result for URL will be

```
http://domain.com/about.php will be http://domain.com/about/
http://domain.com/contact.php will be http://domain.com/contact/
```

Example my URL is `http://domain.com/page.php?id=1`

How to write a code in PHP which the URL will be `http://domain.com/page-name/` according to the `.htaccess` above.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. The `RewriteRule` you show will not rewrite `domain.com/about/` to `domain.com/about.php` like you seem to be suggesting... what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/$ /page.php?name=$1 [L]
```

this is what you search for

http://domain.com/testname/ will be translated to http://domain.com/page.php?name=testname